# TinyMCE - template reload issue

Tags: javascript, tinymce

After I modify template content and save it often truncate but this is not the problem, The problem is, If I save updated template content, I can see it saved and modified on server but It still show the previous template conten when I lload it again ? instead of updated version.
Seems like the template content is stored in some variable which is not updated on save ?

I've tried to clear all variables but it did not helped.
When load template getting unchanged content